# TwoWayView can't change height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've integrated `TwoWayView` with `SpannableGridLayoutManager` in my app.

I want to modify **`height (to height=width/2)`** but this has no effect : the library always render a square view.

Here is my code :

```
int columnNumber = 3
int rowNumber = 6

final SpannableGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new SpannableGridLayoutManager(TwoWayLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL, columnNumber, rowNumber);
mTwoWayView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

I tried to change height in xml, but it has no effet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
style="@style/TwoWayView"
app:twowayview_layoutManager="SpannableGridLayoutManager"
app:twowayview_numColumns="3"
app:twowayview_numRows="6"
app:paddingStart="4dp"
app:paddingEnd="4dp" />
```

In my gradle file :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```